# What is the most pythonic way to support unittest2 features across a range of Python versions?

Tags: python, unittest2

I can think of two ways to ensure that I can use modern features from the unittest library across a wide range of Python versions:

```
try:
    from unittest2 import TestCase
except ImportError:
    from unittest import TestCase
```

or

```
import sys
if sys.verson_info.major>=2 and sys.version_info.minor>=7:
    from unittest import TestCase
else:
    from unittest2 import TestCase
```

Which one of these is more Pythonic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd use the `try` statement. It's an often used idiom. 
Also your `sys` version is wrong for python3.3:

```
>>> if sys.version_info.major>=2 and sys.version_info.minor>=7:
...     from unittest import TestCase
... else:
...     from unittest2 import TestCase
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'unittest2'
```

While it should be:

```
>>> import sys
>>> major, minor = sys.version_info.major, sys.version_info.minor
>>> if (major >= 2 and minor >= 7) or (major >= 3 and minor >= 2):
...     from unittest import TestCase
... else:
...     from unittest2 import TestCase
... 
>>>
```

This shows also that the `try` version is more robust across python's versions.

I often use the `try` variant when I have an "accelerated" version of the module written in C, at the end of the file I put a:

```
try:
    from _accelerated import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

to overwrite the python implementation with the accellerated one.

Comment: Thanks. I don't test against python3 so didn't pick that up.

Answer (score 1):

I don't like the fact that in the second version we have to import another module (`sys`) so my preference is for the first version:

```
try:
    from unittest2 import TestCase
except ImportError:
    from unittest import TestCase
```

EDIT:

It turns out that `pyflakes` and `flake8` are not happy with the version above and will report a "redefinition of unused 'import' from line ... " error or "W402 'TestCase' imported but unused" error. They seem to prefer it to be written as follows:

```
try:
    import unittest2
    TestCase = unittest2.TestCase
except ImportError:
    import unittest
    TestCase = unittest.TestCase
```

Comment: Those tools are not "judges". They simple point *possible* errors/improvements. In this case I'd say they are wrong and your second example is much worse then the first.

Comment: @Bakuriu I tend to agree with you. It's just that some projects have coding standards that rely on those tools.

Answer (score 0):

For those of us who avoid the `from ... import ...` idiom, this imports the right unittest in a manner transparent to the rest of the code:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info < (2, 7):
    import unittest2 as unittest
else:
    import unittest
```