# What's the recommended way to import `unittest` or `unittest2` depending on python version

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have this little `test.py` script I needs to get it running on our CI.  In our local machines, most people use python 2.7, so `import unittest` works.  But in the CI, the environment is python 2.6, which means `import unittest2`.

Currently, I'm invoking the script via

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s %(message)s')
    import xmlrunner
    unittest2.main(testRunner=xmlrunner.XMLTestRunner(output='xml-reports'))
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Python version at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9079036/detect-python-version-at-runtime)

Comment: Rather than clutter your script, just have it use `unittest2` and make your development environment match your CI environment (which just involves installing the redundant `unittest2` module). If and when you switch to Python 2.7 in your CI, *then* modify your script to use `unittest`.

Comment: Thanks, I've found a more closely duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344380/what-is-the-most-pythonic-way-to-support-unittest2-features-across-a-range-of-py

Answer (score 1):

You can check your python version at runtime and assign which import you want.

```
import sys

if sys.version_info[0] == 2 and sys.version_info[1] < 7:
    import unittest2
elif sys.version_info[0] == 2 and sys.version_info[1] == 7:
    import unittest
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use try/except:

```
try:
    import unittest2 as unittest
except ImportError:
    import unittest
```

This should result in the best option for `unittest` being available for the python you are using, but consistently imported as `unittest` in all cases.